# How can I use jQuery's each and click method?

Tags: jquery, arrays, indexing, click, each

I want to make if click button, toggle text in the array.

```
(text[0] -> text[1] -> text[2] -> text[0])
```

And if arrived end of the Array index, return starting of index in the array again.(roop)

I think using each and click method.
But each method is apply at a strech.

How can I do it?

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr = ["uno", "dos", "tre"];
  $("button").click(fuction() {
    $.each(arr, function() {
      $("p").text(arr);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: If your answer was solved, please accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like this, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h89v6are/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr = ["uno", "dos", "tre"];
  var arrIndex = 0;
  $("button").click(function() {
      $("p").text(arr[arrIndex++]);
      arrIndex = arrIndex % arr.length;
  });
});
```

You don't need an each loop. Keep an index for the item in your array, increment this.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I've never know (` arrIndex = arrIndex % arr.length;  `) !

Comment: @user14661, when you ask a question and receive an acceptable answer, you should click the check mark to the left of the answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 var arr = ["uno", "dos", "tre"];
 var count=0;
 var n=arr.length;

 $("button").click(function() {

   count+=1;
   $("p").text(arr[count%n]);


 });

});
```

Comment: Be careful with just putting numbers in. In this case your `2`, the number should actually be 3 but the size of the array might not always be the same so it would make more sense to just use the the size of the array. Also, you missed a mistake the OP made in the spelling of "function".